# How to use agregate Mysql functions with CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

There is a way to use agregate functions with cakephp? like sum() or avg() with find() method.

**UPDATE:**

I missed a line in the book

`array('fields'=>array('Product.type','MIN(Product.price) as price'), 'group' => 'Product.type');`

Showing the basic structure for doing that.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the fields parameter of a find method call, you may pass the field processed by an aggregated function. Example:

```
$Model->find('all',
    array(
        'anything' => array(/* */),
        'fields' => array(
            'SUM (Model.attribute) AS total',
            'OTHERFUNCTION(OModel.other_attribute) AS other'
        ),
        'otherthing' => array(/* */)
    )
);
```

Comment: Yeah i finally make it work :), thanks for the help, i just had to add the group for making use of the function.

Comment: if you looking to improve on that, check out http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields

Comment: Thank your for your help, Now I'm wondering if there are no limitations using it with containable behavior?

Comment: Hmmm... But how do you tell Cake what fields to `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score -5):

In exactly the same way, since CakePHP is just a PHP framework.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection

$query = "SELECT type, SUM(price) FROM products GROUP BY type"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total ". $row['type']. " = $". $row['SUM(price)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yeah i know you can send the query directly to mysql, but I'm wondering if there is a way that cake manages that kind of query using find($type, $params) method and makes the all magic thing, instead of using query(string $query). and manually building the query.

Comment: if you dont know cakephp why bother